# addeventlistener built multiple times

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, addeventlistener

I have an addEventListener built if there is a real-time change in my database:

```
                    db.collection(xx).doc(yy).onSnapshot(user => {
                        accept_button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                          initializeChat();
                        })
```

The `.onSnapshot` is a real-time listener to my database, in another word, if there is a change in my database of document yy, the accept_button appears, then the `initializeChat` function is built into accept_button.

When the document is changed x times, the `addEventListener` function is built x times, and `initializeChat` is executed x times. How do I make such that the same addEventListener function overwrites one another, and `initializeChat` only executes once?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onclick` instead of `addEventListener`.
This will remove multiple event handling.

```
db.collection(xx).doc(yy).onSnapshot(user => {
  accept_button.onclick = function() {
    initializeChat();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to check a flag to see if a listener has been added to the button yet:

```
let listenerAdded = false;
db.collection(xx).doc(yy).onSnapshot(user => {
  if (listenerAdded) {
    return;
  }
  listenerAdded = true;
  accept_button.addEventListener("click", initializeChat);
})
```

Note that there's no need for an extra anonymous function for the `click` callback.

It's usually not a good idea (because only one `onclick` listener can be assigned at a time), but if you're sure no other click listeners will be added to the button, you could also assign to the `onclick` and check it instead:

```
db.collection(xx).doc(yy).onSnapshot(user => {
  if (accept_button.onclick) {
    return;
  }
  accept_button.onclick = initializeChat;
})
```